# Implement Ask-to-Load Image to Website

Tags: web

How to create if a user visits a website but images on those websites won't load until a user press a button on a image to load it. So, initially the images blur. This is the same as Whatsapp's optional setting (which we must to download first in order to view the image clearly) and Twitter Lite's image load (which is what I mean).

The advantages is especially for users who have a limited data usage so loading all the images, including GIF might drain their data usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a very light-weight (possibly in KBs and optionally blur) copy of the image at the time of upload. You can load that first and then on demand, you can use the original one.